# Android/Eclipse: where can I find the /Users/USER_NAME/.android/debug.keystore folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, key, store

To use the Google Maps API, I need to generate a debug API key. For this, I need to find the /Users/USER_NAME/.android/debug.keystore folder...but nothing on my Mac ! Do you know how to find this folder ???

Note that I run Eclipse on a Mac. I checked in Eclipse=>Preferences=>Android=>Debug that the default debug keystore is indeed /Users/USER_NAME/.android/debug.keystore but no way to find it.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open the terminal and type `cd ~/.android`. Next, type `open .` and your `Finder` window will open displaying all the files there, including `debug.keystore`.

Comment: Thanks it works. The problem was that the .android folder is hidden. I managed to generate the key but when I include it in the xml file of my Google Maps activity, I have got a "blank" map (gray empty map with just a grid). Do you know how to solve this issue ? Many thanks.

Comment: @Regis_AG, your best bet is to create a new question and post your code and your `AndroidManifest`. However, one small thing that it could be: do you have the INTERNET `uses-permission` in your `AndroidManifest`? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Answer (score 1):

The folder `.android` is probably hidden. Navigate using the console/terminal.

Comment: Thanks it works. The problem was indeed that the .android folder is hidden. I managed to generate the key but when I include it in the xml file of my Google Maps activity, I have got a "blank" map (gray empty map with just a grid). Do you know how to solve this issue ? Many thanks.

Comment: Either the key is incorrect, or you are doing something wrong in the code. I encountered this problem when adding the project in other Eclipse. So it was an api key problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem before. This UNIX Code solves the error.

In the terminal, type

```
cp -r /var/root/.android /tmp
```

This command will copy the entire .android directory to your temp folder. 
Maybe the reason for this is that android emulator keeps on searching the .android directory from your Mac's tmp folder. The installer keeps that .android directory to your root directory not on the tmp directory. You have to manually copy the directory to your /tmp directory everytime your mac starts.

Mac hides every directory which names starts with a symbol.